# Spring- css and image files are not loaded in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, jsp

In my spring mvc web application, my jsp page is loading without css and images in it, even though I have specified the correct location in the jsp file. Is there anything that I need to add?

This is my JSP Page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Briefcase by TEMPLATED</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slidertron-1.1.js"></script>

<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">BriefCase</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">My Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="banner" class="container">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="viewer">
            <div class="reel">
                <div class="slide"> <a class="link" href="#">Full story ...</a> <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
                <div class="slide"> <a class="link" href="#">Full story ...</a> <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
                <div class="slide"> <a class="link" href="#">Full story ...</a> <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
                <div class="slide"> <a class="link" href="#">Full story ...</a> <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="indicator">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slider').slidertron({
            viewerSelector: '.viewer',
            reelSelector: '.viewer .reel',
            slidesSelector: '.viewer .reel .slide',
            advanceDelay: 3000,
            speed: 'slow',
            navPreviousSelector: '.previous-button',
            navNextSelector: '.next-button',
            indicatorSelector: '.indicator ul li',
            slideLinkSelector: '.link'
        });
    </script> 
</div>
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="onecolumn">
            <h2>Welcome to out website!</h2>
            <p>This is BriefCase , a free, fully standards-compliant CSS template designed by TEMPLATED. The photo used in this template is from Fotogrph. This free template is released under the Creative Commons Attribution license, so you’re pretty much free to do whatever you want with it (even use it commercially) provided you give us credit for it. Have fun :)</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two-column">
            <div class="box-content">
                <h2 class="title title01">Nulla luctus eleifend</h2>
                <p>Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum id, elementum congue, nibh. Suspendisse dictum porta lectus. Donec placerat odio vel elit. Nullam ante orci, pellentesque quis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <h2 class="title title02">Maecenas luctus lectus</h2>
                <p>Curabitur sit amet nulla. Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat vel, suscipit in, mattis placerat, nulla. Sed ac leo. Pellentesque imperdiet. In posuere  odio quisque semper augue mattis maecenas ligula.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sbox1">
            <h2>Fusce fringilla</h2>
            <ul class="list-style1">
                <li class="first">
                    <p>Etiam non felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus, cursus egestas at sem. </p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="link-style">Read More</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Etiam non felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus  at sem. </p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="link-style">Read More</a></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sbox2">
            <h2>Testimonials</h2>
            <p class="testimonial">Pellentesque adipiscing purus ac magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.</p>
            <div class="author"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/pic03.jpg" />" width="80" height="80" alt="" /><span class="name">Juan Dela Cruz</span><span class="position">Company CEO</span><span>MyCompany, LLC</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container">
    <div id="fbox1">
        <h2>Aenean elementum</h2>
        <ul class="style1">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">Consectetuer adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Metus aliquam pellentesque</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suspendisse iaculis mauris</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Urnanet non molestie semper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Proin gravida orci porttitor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="fbox2">
        <h2>Vestibulum luctus</h2>
        <ul class="style1">
            <li class="first"><a href="#">Consectetuer adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Metus aliquam pellentesque</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suspendisse iaculis mauris</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Urnanet non molestie semper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Proin gravida orci porttitor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="fbox3">
        <h2>Etiam malesuada</h2>
        <p>In posuere eleifend odio. Quisque semper augue mattis wisi. Maecenas ligula. Pellentesque viverra vulputate enim. Donec leo. Vivamus fermentum nibh in augue.</p>
        <ul class="style2">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social03.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social01.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social04.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social02.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="copyright" class="container">
    <p>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://templated.co" rel="nofollow">TEMPLATED</a>. Photos by <a href="http://fotogrph.com/">Fotogrph</a>.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is springweb.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.action" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <import resource="springBeanConfiguration.xml"/> -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/"
        cache-period="31556926" />


</beans>
```

And this is my folder structure

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5PcF.png)

Can anyone tellme whythe images in the jsp fileis not shown..

Comment: can you show us some of the code that you have written ? so we can have an idea of what you are doing

Comment: Are you using relative locations?

Comment: I have attached the relevant files in this. Please help me

Comment: try with  <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/social03.png"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `img` sources like

> "images/social03.png"

and a `link` `href` like

> "css/default.css"

These paths are relative locations, they are searching for the given files in the current folder. Since it is highly probable that your page is not inside the root folder and you want to use the locations relative to the root folder, you will need to make sure the paths are relative to the root folder, like

> "/images/social03.png"

and

> "/css/default.css"

Comment: When I add the below lines..<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/jsp/images/"
    cache-period="10000" />..I am getting a 404 error, whereas without this I am getting the page with imgaes not loaded.

Comment: You should leave mvc:resources as it is. Just modify the sources of your img tags and the href of the link.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
<c:url value="/css/default.cs" var="style">
<link href="${style}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

try this utilizing jstl tag library